# Yammer External Network Confusion

Tags: android, yammer

I am working on an Android app that uses an external network with members from many networks. However I have noticed an issue with Authenticating Users from other networks. The login flow of send user to login page, get credentials, call tokens.json, set token to external network, make api calls usually works. However with my credentials, this only works if I am currently looking at the external network on the yammer website. If I am looking at my internal network (the same network whose credentials I am using to log in) I get the initial token fine, but when I attempt to get the token for the external network i get this error: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {bearer=WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="www.yammer.com"}. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue, getting the tokens shouldn't be dependent on what network you are pointing to on the website, should it?

Comment: Is your yammer app registered in the home network or the external network? Also, tokens generated from a home network cannot be used for external networks.

Comment: The Yammer app is registered in the external network. In the deployment scenario users from many different internal networks would be using the application.